# sk_buff struct functions and memory leak

Tags: c, linux, memory-leaks, linux-device-driver

I'm developing some network driver for linux kernel. It is working fine, but it seems that there are memory leaks. I think that two of functions I use are suspected:

```
skb2 = skb_realloc_headroom(skb, size);

skb2 = skb_copy_expand(skb, skb_headroom(skb), size, GFP_ATOMIC);
```

My question is - do those functions make a copy of skb as skb2 and I can safely free skb or not? Or maybe skb2 is just expanded skb and I cannot free them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first reallocates, freeing the original. The second copies, leaving you to free both.

The easiest way to see this is to look at how existing drivers call these functions. So lookup [skb_realloc_headroom](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=skb_realloc_headroom) or [skb_copy_expand](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=skb_copy_expand) on the Linux Cross Reference and click through to the source code of a few drivers.

`skb_realloc_headroom` is generally called like this:

```
skb = skb_realloc_headroom(skb, size);
...
dev_kfree_skb(skb);
```

...while `skb_copy_expand` is called like this:

```
new_skb = skb_copy_expand(skb, skb_headroom(skb) + more_headroom,
                          skb_tailroom(skb), GFP_ATOMIC);
...
dev_kfree_skb(skb);
dev_kfree_skb(new_skb);
```

Comment: skb_realloc_headroom does not free the original skb! Most instances I could find call consume_skb on the original. consume_skb calls __kfree_skb.